# Simple evaluator of Scheme-like expressions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, scheme, racket, interpreter

This is my first nontrivial Haskell program:

```
module Main where
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Env = Map.Map String Expression

data Expression =
  Constant Integer
  | Variable String
  | Add Expression Expression
  | Multiply Expression Expression
  | Let [(String, Expression)] Expression
  | Lambda String Expression
  | Call String Expression
  | Closure Env String Expression
  deriving Show

evaluate :: Env -> Expression -> Expression

evaluate env constant@(Constant _) = constant

evaluate env (Variable name) =
  case Map.lookup name env of
    Just expr -> expr
    _ -> error ("No such variable " ++ name ++ " in Variable expression")

evaluate env (Add aExpr bExpr) =
  let
    aValue = evaluate env aExpr
    bValue = evaluate env bExpr
  in
    case (aValue, bValue) of
      (Constant aInt, Constant bInt) -> Constant (aInt + bInt)
      _ -> error ("Add applied to non-integer")

evaluate env (Multiply aExpr bExpr) =
  let
    aValue = evaluate env aExpr
    bValue = evaluate env bExpr
  in
    case (aValue, bValue) of
      (Constant aInt, Constant bInt) -> Constant (aInt * bInt)
      _ -> error ("Multiply applied to non-integer")

evaluate env (Let bindings body) =
  let
    addBindingsToEnv acc [] = acc
    addBindingsToEnv acc (x : xs) =
      let acc' = Map.insert (fst x) (evaluate env (snd x)) acc
      in addBindingsToEnv acc' xs
  in evaluate (addBindingsToEnv env bindings) body

evaluate env (Lambda param body) = Closure env param body

evaluate env (Call name arg) =
  let
    evaluateClosure (Closure capturedEnv param body) =
      let
        argValue = evaluate env arg
        closureEnv = Map.insert param argValue capturedEnv
      in
        evaluate closureEnv body
  in
    case Map.lookup name env of
      Just x@(Closure _ _ _) -> evaluateClosure x
      Just x -> error ("Variable " ++ name ++ " is not closure in Call expression")
      _ -> error ("No such variable " ++ name ++ " in Call expression")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let result = evaluate
                (Map.fromList [("x", Constant 5)])
                (Let [
                    ("f", (Lambda "p" (Add (Variable "p") (Constant 10)))),
                    ("y", (Constant 20))
                  ]
                  (Let [("temp", (Call "f" (Variable "x")))]
                    (Multiply (Variable "temp") (Variable "y"))))
  putStrLn . show $ result
```

It implements a simple evaluator for a minimal Scheme-like language. Programs are represented using nodes from the `Expression` type. The sample program in the `main` function is equivalent to the following Racket program:

```
#lang racket
(define x 5)
(define result
  (let ([f (lambda (p) (+ p 10))]
        [y 20])
    (let ([temp (f x)])
      (* temp y))))
(print result)
```

I would be interested to hear feedback about my Haskell style and use of idioms and any bugs you might find!

***Update***

Here's a heavily refactored version based on @Sean Perry's feedback:

```
module Main where
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Env = Map.Map String Expression

data ArithmeticExpression = Add Expression Expression
                          | Multiply Expression Expression
                          deriving Show

data Expression = Constant Integer
                | Variable String
                | ArithmeticExpression ArithmeticExpression
                | Let [(String, Expression)] Expression
                | Lambda String Expression
                | Call String Expression
                | Closure Env String Expression
                deriving Show

evaluateArithmeticExpression :: Env -> ArithmeticExpression -> Either String Expression

evaluateArithmeticExpression env (Add aExpr bExpr) = do
  aValue <- evaluate env aExpr
  bValue <- evaluate env bExpr
  case (aValue, bValue) of
    (Constant aInt, Constant bInt) -> Right $ Constant (aInt + bInt)
    _ -> Left "Add applied to non-integer"

evaluateArithmeticExpression env (Multiply aExpr bExpr) = do
  aValue <- evaluate env aExpr
  bValue <- evaluate env bExpr
  case (aValue, bValue) of
    (Constant aInt, Constant bInt) -> Right $ Constant (aInt * bInt)
    _ -> Left "Multiply applied to non-integer"

evaluateClosure :: Env -> String -> Expression -> Expression -> Either String Expression

evaluateClosure capturedEnv param body argValue = do
  evaluate (Map.insert param argValue capturedEnv) body

evaluate :: Env -> Expression -> Either String Expression

evaluate env constant@(Constant _) = Right constant

evaluate env (Variable name) =
  case Map.lookup name env of
    Just expr -> Right expr
    _ -> Left $ "No such variable " ++ name ++ " in Variable expression"

evaluate env (ArithmeticExpression e) =
  evaluateArithmeticExpression env e

evaluate env (Let bindings body) =
  let
    addBindingsToEnv :: Env -> [(String, Expression)] -> Either String Env
    addBindingsToEnv acc [] = Right acc
    addBindingsToEnv acc (x : xs) = do
      xValue <- evaluate env (snd x)
      addBindingsToEnv (Map.insert (fst x) xValue acc) xs
  in
    do
      letEnv <- addBindingsToEnv env bindings
      evaluate letEnv body

evaluate env (Lambda param body) = Right $ Closure env param body

evaluate env (Call name arg) =
  case Map.lookup name env of
    Just (Closure capturedEnv param body) -> do
      argValue <- evaluate env arg
      evaluateClosure capturedEnv param body argValue
    Just x -> Left $ "Variable " ++ name ++ " is not closure in Call expression"
    _ -> Left $ "No such variable " ++ name ++ " in Call expression"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let result = evaluate
                (Map.fromList [("x", Constant 5)])
                (Let [
                    ("f", (Lambda "p" (ArithmeticExpression (Add (Variable "p") (Constant 10))))),
                    ("y", (Constant 20))
                  ]
                  (Let [("temp", (Call "f" (Variable "x")))]
                    (ArithmeticExpression (Multiply (Variable "temp") (Variable "y")))))
  putStrLn . show $ result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the type of `evaluate` to return `Either String Expression`. This also leads to using the Monad to structure the functions.

As an example:

```
evaluate :: Env -> Expression -> Either String Expression
evaluate env (Add aExpr bExpr) = do
    aValue <- evaluate env aExpr  -- if either of these two evaluates fail this call
    bValue <- evaluate env bExpr  -- to evaluate will stop and return the failure 
    case (aValue, bValue) of
      (Constant aInt, Constant bInt) -> Right $ Constant (aInt + bInt)
      _ -> Left "Add applied to non-integer"
```

This way you can catch and handle the `Left` cases. `error` is typically not used in live code.

Personally, I would break the Number expressions out into a separate Math/Num Expression
which would allow for focused optimizations, sub processing, etc.

```
data MathExpression = Add Expression Expression
                    | Multiply Expression Expression
  deriving (Show)

data Expression = Constant Integer
                | Variable String
                | MathExpression
                | Let [(String, Expression)] Expression
                | Lambda String Expression
                | Call String Expression
                | Closure Env String Expression
  deriving Show
```

I find the stacked `let` style really hard to follow and in most cases you do no need them. This is especially true once `evaluate` returns an `Either`.

```
evaluate env (Call name arg) =
    case Map.lookup name env of
      Just (Closure capturedEnv param body) -> do
        argValue <- evaluate env arg
        evaluateClosure param capturedEnv body argValue
      Just x -> Left ("Variable " ++ name ++ " is not closure in Call expression")
      _ -> Left ("No such variable " ++ name ++ " in Call expression")

-- move this out to facilitate unit testing
evaluateClosure :: String -> Env -> Expression -> Expression -> Either String Expression
evaluateClosure param capturedEnv body closure =
  let closureEnv = Map.insert param closure capturedEnv
   in evaluate closureEnv body
```